# No NVIDIA GPU found error, even though I defined Torch to use CPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch

**UPDATE:** I have edited and changed more code, now I dont get an error and it either works but taked hours, or it is stuck on step one

I have tried running Stable Diffusion, the new text2image model. The Problem is: I don´t have a NVIDIA GPU... After a bit of research, I found out you can "force" PyTorch to run on your CPU, not GPU. But up to this point, everything I tried while modifying the existing code, did not work. I always get to the point where it starts sampling, and prints the following error (everyting after the command):

```
Falling back to LAION 400M model...
Global seed set to 42
Loading model from models/ldm/text2img-large/model.ckpt
LatentDiffusion: Running in eps-prediction mode
DiffusionWrapper has 872.30 M params.
making attention of type 'vanilla' with 512 in_channels
Working with z of shape (1, 4, 32, 32) = 4096 dimensions.
making attention of type 'vanilla' with 512 in_channels
data:   0%|                                                                                                                                           | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Sampling:   0%|                                                                                                                                       | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 279, in <module>
    main()
  File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 233, in main
    uc = model.get_learned_conditioning(batch_size * [""])
  File "c:\users\louis\stable-diffusion\ldm\models\diffusion\ddpm.py", line 558, in get_learned_conditioning
    c = self.cond_stage_model.encode(c)
  File "c:\users\louis\stable-diffusion\ldm\modules\encoders\modules.py", line 111, in encode
    return self(text)
  File "C:\Users\louis\anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\louis\stable-diffusion\ldm\modules\encoders\modules.py", line 103, in forward
    tokens = self.tknz_fn(text)#.to(self.device)
  File "C:\Users\louis\anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\louis\stable-diffusion\ldm\modules\encoders\modules.py", line 74, in forward
    tokens = batch_encoding["input_ids"].to(self.device)
  File "C:\Users\louis\anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 216, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```

I already defined to use CPU in text2img.py, so the error of something like "user defined to use cuda, but no cuda device available" is fixed.

So my question(s):
-Is what I´m trying even possible?
-If yes, how should I edit the code to work?
(-Would it even be possible to modify it to work on AMD GPUs using ROCm?)

The Repo: https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion
Using the LAION400m weights, because I currently don´t have access to the SD ones.
I got them using:
`wget -O models/ldm/text2img-large/model.ckpt https://ommer-lab.com/files/latent-diffusion/nitro/txt2img-f8-large/model.ckpt`
Guide I followed:https://github.com/lstein/stable-diffusion

Comment: This may sound unfriendly. However, I really wonder why you try to run a diffusion-based model which requires tremendous computational resources on a CPU machine. A mature deep-learning engineer seldom runs the complete project on his/her own laptop. I understand that you may not be accessible to the GPU server due to some reasons. But why not try some free online services such as Google Colab? Sry for not directly answering your question, but I think it can be more reasonable to alter your environment instead of seeking a reply that is hard to obtained :)